# This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression inSQL

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

Need the count of the subquery

--DM reached Before But Again NOT reached  Again for the last - 60 days - VIP

```
SET @MainQuery = 'SET @DMNotReachedAgainForLastSixtyDaysVIP = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SMSCH.Cgvak_Comh_Icode) 
FROM Cgvak_Sms_Company_Header SMSCH 
JOIN Cgvak_Sms_Company_Detail SMSCD ON SMSCD.Cgvak_Comd_Comh_Icode = SMSCH.Cgvak_Comh_Icode 
JOIN [dbo].[Cgvak_Sms_User_Master] SMSUM ON SMSUM.Cgvak_User_Icode = SMSCH.Cgvak_Comh_AssignBDE_Icode
WHERE (SMSCD.Cgvak_Comd_Call_date >= DATEADD(DAY, -60, GETDATE())) AND SMSCD.Cgvak_Comd_SpoketoStatus = ''N''  AND ' + RTRIM(@DynamicQuery) + ' 
AND SMSCD.Cgvak_Comd_Comh_Icode IN (SELECT DISTINCT CSCH.Cgvak_Comh_Icode FROM Cgvak_Sms_Company_Header CSCH 
JOIN Cgvak_Sms_Company_Detail CSCD ON CSCD.Cgvak_Comd_Comh_Icode = CSCH.Cgvak_Comh_Icode 
WHERE  CSCH.Cgvak_Comh_VIPAC = ''Y'' AND CSCD.Cgvak_Comd_Call_date <= DATEADD(DAY, -60, GETDATE()) 
AND CSCH.Cgvak_Comh_DMSpokeStatus = 1 AND CSCH.Cgvak_Comh_Icode = CSCD.Cgvak_Comd_Comh_Icode))

EXECUTE sp_executesql @MainQuery , N'@DMNotReachedAgainForLastSixtyDaysVIP BIGINT OUTPUT', @DMNotReachedAgainForLastSixtyDaysVIP = @DMNotReachedAgainForLastSixtyDaysVIP OUTPUT
```

I'm passing dynamic queries from front end to this SP. But it shows , Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Please show some effort on asking a question, please format & give some explanation

Comment: Sorry Bro, New to this. Please look into it now

Comment: What's in `@DynamicQuery`? The easiest way to debug dynamic sql is to print the query instead of execute it and then you can see it as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem in the code you posted.   The problem must be in `RTRIM(@DynamicQuery)`.